# Converting a 3D integral into a 2D integral (L.C. Evans PDE book)

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations

## **Background information.**

I have taken it upon myself, over the next year or so, to read the entirety of *Partial Differential Equations* (2nd Ed.) by Lawrence C. Evans. (You can easily find a copy of the text online.) Though it's notorious for its difficulty, I am finding it reasonably accessible so far. I'm on chapter 2, section 4, which is about the wave equation. Evans first builds the solutions to the wave equation Cauchy problem in one, two, and three dimensions before generalizing to higher dimensions. It turns out to be convenient to first solve the Cauchy problem in 1D, use this to build the solution to the 3D Cauchy problem, and then using the *method of descent* to use this 3D solution to solve the 2D problem. The source of this problem is from page 73.

## **Problem Statement.**

First, let's establish some notation. Let $g:\Bbb R^2\to \Bbb R$ be given. Define $\bar g:\Bbb  R^3\to\Bbb R$ be defined as $\bar g(x_1,x_2,x_3):=g(x_1,x_2)$. (I.e $\bar g$ is simply constant in its third argument.) Now define

### $$\mathbb B^k\big((x_1,\dots,x_k),r\big)=\left\{(y_1,\dots ,y_k)\in\mathbb R^k:\sum_{i=1}^k (y_i-x_i)^2<r^2\right\}$$

Be the $k$ dimensional ball centered at $(x_1,\dots ,x_k)$ with radius $r$. Finally, we use as a notation $\overline{(x_1,x_2)}:=(x_1,x_2,0).$ With these pieces of notation established, let $x\in\mathbb R^2$ and $t\in\mathbb R_+$ and consider the integral

### $$F(x,t):=\int\limits_{\partial\mathbb B^3(\bar x,t)}\bar g(y)\mathrm d^2 y\tag{1}$$

This is an integral on the boundary of a three dimensional ball. Since we are trying to solve the wave equation in 2D, we would like to convert this integral to an integral in **two** dimensions. Evans claims that

### $$F(x,t)=2\int\limits_{\mathbb B^2(x,t)}g(y)~\sqrt{1+\left|\nabla \gamma(y-x)\right|^2}~\mathrm d^2 y\tag{2}$$

Where $\nabla$ is the **two** dimensional gradient (taken of course WRT $y$) and

### $$\gamma:\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R \\ \gamma(z)=\sqrt{t^2-|z|^2}$$

Evans gives this formula with no explanation and I am simply unable to put together the pieces. I am able to figure out that

### $$\partial \mathbb B^3(\bar x,t)=\partial\mathbb B^3\big((x_1,x_2,0),t\big)\\
=\left\{(y_1,y_2,y_3)\in\mathbb R^3 : {y_3}^2+(y_1-x_1)^2+(y_2-x_2)^2=t^2\right\} \\ 
=\left\{(y_1,y_2,y_3)\in\mathbb R^3 : (y_1,y_2)\in \partial\mathbb B^2\left((x_1,x_2),\sqrt{t^2-{y_3}^2}\right)\right\}$$

Which means that we should be able to rewrite $(1)$ as  (letting $y=(y_1,y_2)$)

### $$F(x,t)=\int_{-t}^t\int\limits_{\partial\mathbb B^2\left(x,\sqrt{t^2-{s}^2}\right)}g(y)~\mathrm d^1 y~\mathrm ds$$

But I don't know how to use this to construct $(2)$.

## **My question.**

How to construct $(2)$ starting from the definition $(1)$ ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The factor $\sqrt{1+|\nabla\gamma|^2}$ is the area element for the sphere of radius $t$. Going from (1) to (2) can be obtained from the formula for a surface integral from multivariable calculus, namely if $S$ is a smooth hypersurface in $\mathbb{R}^3$ parametrized by $r:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^3$, then

$$\int_S f(y) dS(y) = \int_{r^{-1}(S)} f(u,v) |r_u \times r_v| du dv $$

Where $r_u,r_v$ are the $u,v$ partial derivatives of $r$.

Here you can use the parametrization $r(u,v) = \bar{x}+(u,v,\sqrt{t^2-|(u,v)|^2})$ for the top half of the sphere, and since $\bar{g}$ is symmetric about the horizontal ($xy$) plane, its contribution to the bottom half of the sphere is the same as its contribution to the top half, hence the factor of 2 in (2).

Comment: Oh, I see now. Thanks so much.